# PHP Regex match issue

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble matching â character in the string.

For example

```
if (preg_match("/C[â]mera/i", "Câmera Canon ")) // returns false
```

but

```
if (preg_match("/C[a]mera/i", "Camera Canon ")) // returns true
```

Any idea? why it's working with a but not with â?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked you file encoding?

Comment: you mean .php file encoding? how do we set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with unicode strings (ie. UTF-8), you should use the `u` flag:

```
preg_match("/C[â]mera/iu", "Câmera Canon ")
```

> [**u (PCRE_UTF8)**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if (preg_match("/C[\pL00E2]mera/u", "Câmera Canon "))
```

Comment: This would match `preg_match("/C[\pL00E2]mera/u", "Cemera Canon ")` too f.ex.